# How to decipher lamba/ anonymous epxression statements correctly

Tags: scala

I often get confused when I see scala lamba/ anonymous expressions like this:

```
def someFunc(req: RequestHeader)(f: Blah => Option[Car] => Truck): Truck =
```

or

```
 def someFunc2(...) = someFunc(3) { a => b =>
```

So what often confuses me or what isn't immediately obvious is what the parameter is or return type.

Can someone help break these types of statements down for me?

Comment: `Blah => Option[Car] => Truck` is a **Function** which receives a **Blah** and returns a **Function** which takes an **Option[Truck]** and returns a **Truck**. `someFunc(3) { a => b => ` is calling that method, where `a => b =>` means it is creating the first function that returns another function. - Being honest, I haven't see code like that and sounds like someone trying to imitate **Haskell** like syntax in **Scala**. I would just rather use a function of two arguments.

Comment: The return type of what? The method or the function? The return type of the method is what is after the `:` colon. The return type of the function is what is after the `=>` arrow.